# Reference for IDockableWindow

Tags: arcobjects, .net, add-in

I am new to ArcObjects .NET. I am trying to open a dockable window with the following code:

```
public class CAD_Test_01_button : ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Button
{
    public CAD_Test_01_button()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnClick()
    {

        UID dockWinID = new UIDClass();
        dockWinID.Value = ThisAddIn.IDs.DockableWindow1;

        // Use GetDockableWindow directly as we want the client IDockableWindow not the internal class
        IDockableWindow dockWindow = ArcMap.DockableWindowManager.GetDockableWindow(dockWinID);
        dockWindow.Show(true);

    }

    protected override void OnUpdate()
    {
    }
}
```

But I get the errors:

> Error: The type or namespace name 'IDockableWindow' could not be found
> (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Error: The name 'ArcMap' does not exist in the current context

What references could I be missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below works for me:

```
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem;

namespace ArcMapAddin2
{
    public class MyButton1 : ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Button
    {
        private static IDockableWindow _DockWindow;
        public MyButton1()
        {
            UID dockWinID = new UIDClass();
            dockWinID.Value = @"Microsoft_ArcMapAddin2_MyDockwin";
            _DockWindow = ArcMap.DockableWindowManager.GetDockableWindow(dockWinID);
        }

        protected override void OnClick()
        {
            _DockWindow.Show(!_DockWindow.IsVisible());
        }

        protected override void OnUpdate()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IDockableWindow is in the ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework namespace - reference it and add a using statement.

ArcMap will not work except in VBA.  You need to create your manager from the "hook" object in the OnCreate event.

```
IApplication m_app = hook as IApplication;
IDockableWindowManager pDocWinMgr = m_app as IDockableWindowManager;
```

Comment: `ArcMap` is a helper class that is included with ArcMap add-ins if you use the add-in template wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Per default there is the following method included in the `Config.Designer.cs` of `Config.esriaddinx`:

```cs
internal static ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UID ToUID(this System.String id) {
    ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UID uid = new ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UIDClass();
    uid.Value = id;
    return uid;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
IDockableWindow pDockableWindow = ArcMap.DockableWindowManager.GetDockableWindow(
    ThisAddIn.ToUID(
        ThisAddIn.IDs.<NAME OF YOUR DOCKABLE WINDOW>
    )
);
```